# Muti select uiimagepickercontroller like facebook app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an app, In which user can select multiple picture and upload it server.

As of now i am using [QBImagePickerController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/qbimagepickercontroller) for selecting multiple pictures but client demanding us to make mirror of facebook app's image selection functionality.

I know we can customise **QBImagePickerController** but it will consume little more time. So is there any third party control exact like facebook app?

**Facebook app screenshot**
[image]

Comment: It's kind difficult to find an exact controller as you want it. Besides it won't take you much time to edit QBImagePickerController.

Answer (score -1):

This will definitely help you

[LINK is](http://code4app.net/ios/Multiple-Selection-Picker-View/4f87d19b06f6e74532000000)

Source Code is [here](https://github.com/alexleutgoeb/ALPickerView)

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Legit Means?? I am not able to understand.

Comment: @PurushottamSen it means your answer doesn't make any sense.